# react-text-fun rendering text twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blotter

I've been playing around with some libraries and tested out react-text fun. I placed the blotter script in my html file and installed the library. When I test out an effect, I get two rendered elements on my page. Any ideas on how to fix this?

public HTML:

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/blotterjs-fork@0.1.0/build/blotter.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { LiquidDistortionText } from 'react-text-fun'
// styles
import { Header, HeroContainer } from './Home.styles'

// components

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Header>
      <HeroContainer>
        <LiquidDistortionText
          text="Text"
          speed={0.25}
          rotation={0.2}
          distortX={0}
          distortY={0.2}
          noiseAmplitude={0.1}
          noiseVolatility={1}
        />
      </HeroContainer>
    </Header>
  )
}
```

[rendered webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVzxp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct. You should look at your Header Component and HeroContainer. Maybe you used children twice times.